# Enabling Root Login

Tags: login, root

I supposedly enabled a root login by setting a password for root by means of the command:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Yet on the login screen after reboot when I use the username root the password I set earlier with the above command does not work. Should it?

Right now the only way I can be root is while logged in as user number 1000, and using the command:

```
sudo -i
```

OS is Ubuntu 22.04 Studio Jammy

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release details; nor what type of Ubuntu product?  Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? what release etc...

Comment: You really have to consider why you need root login with a password - this *could* be a huge security risk (there is a reason it's disabled by default). Instead, consider allowing root login only with SSH and keypairs. And if you need local root, doing it with `sudo -i` is the preferable option.

Comment: One of the goals of the years-long migration from X to Wayland was *specifically* so the desktop would not be run as root anymore.

Comment: Login as root enable was intended to be temporary. There is this problem I have for which I opened this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419676/computer-fails-to-turn-off-its-own-power . I wanted to find out if I was logged in as root in the GUI, the power down would work if commanded using the GUI icons, and not just the "sudo poweroff" command.